# translate foreign keys from one column to values in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables

**InstrumentOperation**

```
   InstrumentStatusId    StatusDataKeyId
         1                       0
         2                       0 
         3                       0
         4                       0
         5                       0
```

**InstrumentStatus**

```
        Id       Name
         1      ACTIVE
         2     INACTIVE
         3     MAINTENANCE
         4     SERVICE  
         5     BROKEN
```

**InstrumentStatusDataKey**

```
        Id       Name
         1     MAINTENANCE
         2     SERVICE  
         3     BROKEN
```

`InstrumentStatusId` in `InstrumentOperation` references the Id of an entry in `InstrumentStatus`. Same with `StatusDataKeyId` and `InstrumentStatusDataKey`.

I want the `StatusDataKeyId` column in the `InstrumentOperation` table to be populated with the `Id` of the entry in `InstrumentStatusDataKey` that correctly corresponds to the `Id` of the entry in `InstrumentStatus` with a matching name if it exists, otherwise, keep a `0`. For example the answer would be:

**InstrumentOperation**

```
   InstrumentStatusId    StatusDataKeyId
         1                       0
         2                       0 
         3                       1
         4                       2
         5                       3
```

The query I came up with only works if all of the entries in `InstrumentStatusId` are `1` except for a single row...

```
UPDATE InstrumentOperation SET StatusDataKeyId = (
    SELECT
        InstrumentStatusDataKey.Id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM InstrumentStatusDataKey) AS InstrumentStatusDataKey
        JOIN InstrumentStatus ON InstrumentStatus.Name = InstrumentStatusDataKey.Name
        JOIN (SELECT * FROM InstrumentOperation) AS InstrumentOperation ON InstrumentOperation.InstrumentStatusID = InstrumentStatus.Id
) WHERE InstrumentOperation.InstrumentStatusId != (SELECT Id FROM InstrumentStatus WHERE InstrumentStatus.Name = "ACTIVE");
```

The error I get is `Subquery returns more than 1 row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow this logic correctly, you simply want to `join` the tables together and set the appropriate key:

```
update InstrumentOperation io join
       InstrumentStatus ins
       on io.InstrumentStatusId = ins.id join
       InstrumentStatusDataKey isd
       on isd.name = ins.name
    set StatusDataKeyId = isd.id;
```